# How to compare salesforce custom encrypted text field with user input in customer portal site?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, encryption

I have an encrypted text field on the `Contact` object. How can I compare this date of birth field with user input from site page?

**In Layout**

[image: Encrypted Output]

**Configuration**

[image: Field Configuration]

**Input**

[image: Date Input]

Comment: Possible duplicate? [How to decrypt encrypted text generated using generateDigest method and SHA256 algorithm](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126831/how-to-decrypt-encrypted-text-generated-using-generatedigest-method-and-sha256-a)

Comment: No... This is for salesforce default encrypted field decrypt and compare with user input.

Answer (score 2):

First, according to what I've read, one cannot decrypt information in Salesforce that's already encrypted. Instead, a User can be given the "view encrypted" permission" which unfortunately is system wide. That means you'd need to be very careful about exposing anything to them with encryption if you granted each portal user that permission set. Instead of displaying that to them, you'd want to only expose it in the controller that was running under their permissions.

Next, encryption is merely masking of contents. It it not a secure "cipher" or encoded field. See @sfdcfox answer to this question: [Use-Case for Encrypted Custom Fields and why are they rendered as input type="text" and not as type="password" on standard UI?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43949/use-case-for-encrypted-custom-fields-and-why-are-they-rendered-as-input-type-te?rq=1) for more on encryption.

That having been said. Your `Date of birth` input field will first need to be converted to a string in your controller. Once converted, you'd presumably be able to compare the two if the new Date of birth field is converted to an encrypted field. You'd simply use string methods like `equals` or `contains` along with `length()`. You might be able to do it without applying the encryption, but as I've not tried it, I wouldn't want to say for certain and don't have time at the moment to test. Will leave that part to you.

Comment: When you say it's just masking the field, what does that indicate given that Encrypted fields are encrypted using AES.   "Encrypted fields are encrypted with 128-bit master keys and use the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) algorithm" from https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&language=en. By masking, do you mean that it's not encrypted until it's stored in the db?

Comment: Was referring to context of these statements on page you pointed to: "You can still validate the values of encrypted fields using validation rules or Apex. Both work regardless of whether the user has the 'View Encrypted Data' permission." & "Encrypted field data is not always masked in the debug log. Encrypted field data is masked if the Apex request originates from an Apex Web service, a trigger, a workflow, an inline Visualforce page, or a Visualforce email template. In other cases, encrypted field data isn’t masked in the debug log, like for example when running Apex Dev Console"

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply. By converting encrypted dob to string and comparing the string with user input from customer portal is not worked. comparing both is always false. 
How i will use this encrypted Birthdate__c field in Query where clause ? is there any workaround ? @crmprogdev

Comment: According to what I've read, SF doesn't allow you to decrypt a string from an encrypted field. I suggest you look at the docs that @gorav referred to along with the Apex Code Developer's Guide where those methods are covered.

Comment: as per @gorav we can't get the decrypted value of encrypted fields in apex code also if we have "View Encrypted Data" Permission. that is what you are trying to mean. right ?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I'm saying we can't decrypt it for comparison or export. The platform will decrypt it for display. The platform will do validation for us and other things. There are methods for working with encrypted data such as the [Crypto Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm%23apex_classes_restful_crypto) and others in the Apex Docs.

Comment: FYI `Apex` code can always see encrypted data.

Comment: @AdrianLarson If the encryption key is available, indeed it can. The exceptions being fields encrypted using Salesforce Shield Encryption which cannot be searched via Apex using SOQL, etc unless the search feature is enabled for the field when it's created.