# How to decrypt encrypted text generated using generateDigest method and SHA256 algorithm

Tags: apex, force.com, encryption, decrypt

I have a DOB field(Type-Text) in Contact object, In Before insert event i have encrypted and show in encrypted form in page layout.

[image]

```
contact con = [select id, DOB__c From contact where id = '00363000005aOFk'];
system.debug('@Contact@'+con);
string str = con.DOB__c;
Blob b = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(str));
String afterEnc = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b);
system.debug('@After Encrypting@'+afterEnc);
```

**But in query i need to decrypt this to actual text and compare with the user input. but i am not able to decrypt this ?**

Please Advice

Comment: can you add the logic for encrypt the text?

Comment: Are you sure, you are using SHA-256 to encrypt? SHA-256 is a cryptographic (one-way) hash function, so there is no direct way to decode it. If you want to encrypt and decrypt you can use AES256.

Comment: @Ratan 
I have added the code snippet for encrypting DOB.

Comment: @SarojBera
Is there any other option except Crypto Key for doing this.

Comment: Please check this link on how to encrypt/decrypt https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class

Comment: Are you just trying to compare equality or something more fancy?